# Can you instruct EF to ignore tables that already exist

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity, entity-framework-migrations

My application has a one context that is injected using Autofac. I also have plugins which created and maintained their own contexts on the same database. I'm bringing it all in-line now so that the plugins just use the main context.

The issue I now face is that because the tables already exist in the database, I can't `update-database` because it says `PluginTable` already exists in the database. I can't do an `add-migration` and then remove the Up / Down entries because the plugins aren't within the same project.

Note: I think this is only an issue because the tables already exist so I need to get the current migration entries up to date so it doesn't try and recreate the tables.

Note: I considered re-building the migration file but again, the same problem will happen because add migration doesn't work.

I don't know what code to post that will help with this but I'm just wondering if we can tell ef to ignore tables that already exist on its creation process (this sounds daft as I type it but I'm not sure what else to do).

EDIT: Perhaps the question I should be asking is how to get the `add-migration` to take note of the other projects so I can just do a blank add migration and get the migration file up to date

Comment: Afaik you can't have code first and database first in the same project in Entity Framework. Can't you do it in separate projects?

Comment: Do you mean enable migrations on each plugin as well and add the migrations specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by the can't add-migration, but if you need to run a migration to establish a baseline:

```
Add-Migration MyBaseline –IgnoreChanges
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#option1

Comment: I enabled migrations on each plugin and manage them against the plugin then for the first migration, I run this command which brings it all up to date. Excellent and thanks (beats creating a migration and deleting the up / down code).

Comment: The current approach is to clear up and down methods. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26870

Comment: @al.koval Correct. This answer is for EF 6 which supported `IgnoreChanges`. EF Core did not have this.